# How to know that mongodump operation failed

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodump

I run a mongodump command from php:

```
$cmd = "mongodump --host=" . $host . " --port=" . $port . " --db=" . $db . " --username=". $username . " --collection=" . $collectionName . " --out=" . $path . " -p " . $password;
$res = shell_exec($cmd);
```

Sometimes the connection to the mongo server is down and the dump operation fails, or even the authorisation to the server fails, but I have no way of knowing it through my code.

I have found a temporary solution, which is far from being a good one, by checking the presence of both .bson and .metadata.json files, while the metadata.json file is the more important check, as if the dump fails in the middle, the .bson file still exists, but the metadata.json file is not present

Is there any other way to verify the result of the dump operation ?

Comment: Can't you echo the result from $res like `echo "<ul><li>" . $cmd . "</li><li>".$res."</li></ul>");`?

Comment: @chridam Nope, the $cmd result is not providing any valuable info at all